# How does Route53 give priority to wildcard subdomains?

Tags: amazon-route53

I currently have the following subdomains on my Route53:

`website.com` => elb1

`dashboard.website.com` => elb1

`staging.website.com` => elb2

`cdn.website.com` => cloudfront

I'd like to add a wildcard subdomain for a new feature that would match any subdomain and point the same elb, like this:

`*.website.com` => elb1

I've added it and it seems to work, but now I'm wondering, how does it give priority if the user navigates to `staging.website.com` -- will it match `*.website.com` or `staging.website.com` first? And should I do anything differently?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

DNS will always match the most specific record first. In your case, the wildcard record will act as a fallthrough, catching any requests that don't match the non-wildcard records.